# How to provide equal width for 80% columns in all the rows in div with css?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using flex property to display the progress of work in an office. I have multiple rows of data displaying. But the child div width is showing differently on each row depends on a number of children inside the parent div. How to show every time equal width for all same values ?

[image]

Comment: Hello, can you show us your code so we can help you?

Comment: You probably want to set flex-grow and flex-shrink to 0.

Comment: when I set fo fex-grow and felx-shrink as 0 same width is showing in equal size everywhere. But if the total width going beyond 100% the content is exceeding the fixed width of the div. I need to show everything with in a container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thank you 04FS for the information on flex-grow and flex-shirnk to make zero. I have changed the CSS for my flex box and given the width of each column in %. This solved my issue
#parent 
{
  width: 750px;
  display: flex;
}
.grow { 
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```